# How to upload any type of file in phonegap

Tags: php, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to phonegap , creating an app in phonegap , in which i want to upload file to remote server .when user click on upload file icon , i want user to redirect to SD card files and user can select any file either image , video , doc or txt file .

Below is the code i'm using . I'm trying it from last three days but unable to make it work as needed .

Issues i want to resolve

1) Dialog box with all the files in SD card as currently as currently only images are visible on clicking the upload image .

2) Allow user to upload any type of file , currently i'm able to upload image file only and that too converted to jpg  , user must able to view all the files in sd card .

3) As soon as user click upload image the image is uploaded to folder , i want image to go to remote server , once user has submitted the form .

```
<script>
function getImage() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
            alert('get picture failed');
        }, {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
            //sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });

    }
function onError() {
            alert('fehler resolve file system');
        }
function cameraError() {
            alert('fehler');
        }
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        console.log(options.fileName);
        window.localStorage.setItem("imag",options.fileName);
        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "{website url}/upload.php", function(result){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }, function(error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }, options);

}
</script>

<!----------html-------------!>
<img src="upload-icon.png"  onclick="getImage()">
<!---html end----------------!>
```

Thanks in advance for your help and your time .